# Configuring Airtel Beetel 450TC1 ADSL2+ Router for local RJ45 cable internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Please help me configure my Airtel Beetel 450TC1 ADSL2+ Router for local RJ45 cable internet (my ip lookup suggests my ISP name as smartlinklink broadband services pvt ltd)

Here are my current settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm9Sq.jpg

Have disabled VLAN, ACL, CWMP as read on various forums but still can't get it working, please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 192.168.1.1 page with username “Admin” and your Password.
2. Go to the Interface Setup > LAN page and under DHCP section, select Disabled.
3. Click Save at the Bottom of the page.
4. Connect the ISP cable on LAN1 port and Restart the Modem.
5. Ready to use. If you are not able to connect to modem page at 192.168.1.1 then reset the modem.

This should work I guess. Please reply with your observation.